# Numbers between $1$ to $80$ with non-terminating decimal representations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

@Edit
**MyApproach1**

1) I first calculated all the multiples of $2$ i.e : $2$,$4$,$6$......$80$

Number of terms are $80$=$2$+(n-$1$)$2$ => n=$40$

2) Then, I calculated All the multiples of $5$ i.e : $5$,$10$,$15$......$80$

Number of terms are $80$= $5$+(n-$1$)$5$ => n=$16$

I have to subract $8$ terms from it as they occur in both.i.e $10$,$20$,$30$,$40$..etc

so Final Ans would be 80-48=32

> Is there any other approach through which I can solve the problem fast?

Comment: Instead of looking at many prime numbers which are not 2 or 5, why not look at only the prime numbers that are 2 and 5?

Comment: @justintakro No, your new approach is wrong, you were correct first.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @justintakro Please note your solution is incorrect. Remove your latest edits, leave the correct first approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's count the number of terminating decimals first.

It is easy to see that if $\frac{1}{x}$ has some terminating decimal expansion, where $x\in\mathbb{N}$, then $x=2^a5^b$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{N_0}$.

It is easy to list these numbers systematically:

1. $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64$ (powers of 2)
2. $5, 10, 20, 40, 80$ ($5$ times a power of 2)
3. $25, 50$ ($5^2$ times a power of 2)

Hence there are 14 of these numbers in total.

Hence $80-14=66$ of these numbers do not have terminating decimals.

Comment: You also need to know that if $x=2^a5^b$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb N_0$, then $\frac{1}{x}$ has some terminating decimal expansion, but it's easy to see.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably easy to count those that are terminating. These will be any of the form $2^n5^m$. Namely: 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 16, 20, 25, 32, 40, 50, 64, 80.

So 80-14=66.